# iPhone local notification in different application states

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, notifications

I'm using local notification in my app but have a problem handling them correctly.

When app is running, and active, in `didReceiveLocalNotification` I can fetch user settings from `NSUserDefaults` and handle the repeating notification, and cancel it if fire date isn't the day it should fire, or show an alert if it's correct date.

However, when app is running, but inactive, the notification will fire although it shouldn't.
Same thing when app is not running, the notification will fire although it shouldn't.

**Question**
When app is not running, and when app is inactive, how can I access `NSUserDefaults` and cancel the notification before the alert show up?

**Edited answer**
The reason I had to ask this was because of bad app design and logic. I tried to set repeating local notification no matter what settings user has set and access `NSUserDefaults` in it although I should have access user settings first in app itself and then set notifications accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. a `UILocalNotification` is handled by iOS and not your app.
Only when your app is active the notification get directly pushed to you app.
In all other cases the os will just show the notification.

Comment: hmm... so if i create a notification to be fired every day they will always be fired and shown if app is not running – and not being able to cancel them programmatically? That's ridiculous! :(

Comment: Yes that's what there there for. To make it possible to alert the user for something. I think you are using `UILocalNotification` for something where they are not ment to be used for. Thus making it no so ridiculous.

Comment: trying to fire a repeating alarm, notification, and cancel it if user has disabled notifications from my app settings. Any suggestions for other approach?

Comment: Well the user can still cancel you notification from the settings apps. Thus making it impossible for you app to receive any notifications. If you want the alarm only to be active if the app is running you can use a `NSTimer` with the [`initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-BBCGEHGC) method to make it go of on a specific date.